# jQuery get height from CSS or dynamically for toggle?

Tags: jquery, css, height, toggle

I have the following code but I'm building a responive site so the height needs to be dynamic to the content. It's set at 0 so the div appears closed then on click it needs to set the height. Can I set this in the CSS (using different heights with media queries) and have it pulled in?

```
$("#contactArea").css('height', '0px');

$("a.contact").toggle( 
            function () { 
                $("#contactArea").animate({height: "180px"}, {queue:false, duration: 800, easing: 'easeOutBack'}) 
            }, 
            function () { 
                $("#contactArea").animate({height: "0px"}, {queue:false, duration: 800, easing: 'easeOutBack'})  
            } 
    );
```

Many thanks.

Comment: How about min-height on the area you want to expand? And if the content is bigger than the initial value it will expand..

Comment: Looks like jQuery doesn't know the start and end height if you do what you want. But with CSS3 transitions it works: http://jsfiddle.net/9vPaK/1/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to define a class for the closed and opened divs, with the responsive css assigned to the open class div.  Then onclick you can use jQuery to change the class of the div with a command like this

```
$("#contactArea").attr('class', 'newClass');
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've done the following but now i don't get the animation.
$("a.contact").toggle( 
function () { 
 $("#contactArea").attr('class', 'newClass').animate({queue:false, duration: 800, easing: 'easeOutBack'});
                }, 
                function () { 
$("#contactArea").animate({queue:false, duration: 800, easing: 'easeOutBack'})  
    } 
  );

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed that requirement.  In that case you might want to have it set to display:none to start instead of having the height set to 0, and then use .show() to reveal it.  You should be able to animate that properly, and then you'd only need one class with show and hide methods with the animations attached used to toggle.  Does that fit what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, yes you can!

To animate the height to the set CSS height, use the 'toggle' option:

```
$("#contactArea").animate({height: 'toggle'},0);

$("a.contact").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#contactArea").animate({height: "toggle"}, {queue:false, duration: 800, easing: 'easeOutBack'})     
}); ​
```

Secondly, use `click()` not `toggle(with two functions)` as the latter is deprecated.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyEsq/1/)